# Use Shamir algorithm to encrypt data set of numbers (approx. 100,000)

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

How to use Shamir algorithm to encrypt data set of numbers (huge data about 100,000 number)?

I'm new to java and shamir algorithm.
I was implemented encryption string with shamir algorithm,for example encrypt "hello world" to six pieces,and require 3 pieces to decrypt "hello world".
But I'm want to encrypt one by one a huge data set of numbers(about 100,000 or larger item's).
How can I implement it?

Comment: Never shy to share the code you have tried. Code attracts more people here on SO to provide help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shamir's secret sharing algorithm isn't terribly difficult to implement, but you do need to understand how to create the tables to perform discrete logarithm and exponentiation in a field. You ought to be able to understand the general outline from [this application](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/), and port your understanding to Java.

When you say you want to encrypt a huge set of numbers one-by-one, I don't really understand the problem. Do you mean that you'll treat each number in the set as a secret, and create shares from it? And repeat this process independently for each number in the set? If you can split "Hello, World!", you should be able do it again and again. What's the difficulty?

This isn't a good format for collaborating on complete programs. It's targeted more at helping you spot a problem with a couple of lines of code. Please be more specific in your questions.

Comment: Yes,I'll treat each number in the set as a secret,and create shares from it.And repeat this process.